# Get parent directory of shell script's directory

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script here:

```
/node_modules/.bin/exec.sh
```

in the exec.sh script, I want to obtain the path of the directory's parent directory that the script is contained in (not pwd/cwd!). I can obtain the containing directory like so:

```
`dirname $0`
```

which will yield:

```
/node_modules/.bin
```

but I am looking to get at one directory higher, I just want to get

```
/node_modules
```

I am having trouble searching for the answer, my guess is:

```
`dirname $1`
```

but just a guess, not sure if that's right at all. Can anyone give an explanation of how to do this and how it works?

Comment: no, not at all, this has nothing to do with cwd/pwd

Comment: @AlexanderMills It has everything to do with that. Get the parent directory of your target. Then get the parent directory of *that* directory.

Comment: no, it has to do with the directory that contains the script, not the current working directory or present working directory, they could be very different...imagine you execute the script like so ../../exec.sh, thanks though

Comment: @AlexanderMills I actually had selected the wrong answer from the list of possible duplicates. I retracted my close vote for now.

Comment: you can use parameter expansion.. `p='/node_modules/.bin/exec.sh'; echo "${p%/*/*}"`

Comment: @Ouroborus..."Get the parent directory of your target. Then get the parent directory of that directory." (Where target is the bash script). What does that have to do with PWD/CWD again?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Run dirname twice (nested).

```
~$ dirname $PWD
/home
~$ dirname `dirname $PWD`
/
~$
```

Comment: this is close, but I think it is $(dirname \`dirname $0\`)

Answer (score 7):

I believe the answer is

```
$(dirname $(dirname "$0"))
```

don't forget about the double-quotes around "$0"